# What is the meaning of 'I did not lift a finger to save his character'?

Tags: phrases

I read it in chapter 20 of the invisible man.

Comment: It means that the author failed to include any context to support the character.

Comment: Collins Dictionary: [**not lift a finger**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/not-lift-a-finger) (informal) *- to not help someone do something, usually because you are too lazy*.

Comment: The "lifting of a finger" is a metaphor for an absolutely minimal amount of work. (Always used in the negative) Saying someone "didn't lift a finger" implies they were not prepared to make even the most miniscule effort - usually in order to help someone, or prevent a bad outcome.

Comment: FWIW: https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/120/the-invisible-man/2500/chapter-20/ and https://books.google.com/books?id=zXpCDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=%22I+did+not+lift+a+finger+to+save+his+character%22&source=bl&ots=AgjzCbJdlr&sig=ACfU3U2R0w9zuU7E7WZSdJFiNG5GjiAbog&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHut6NpsThAhWzOn0KHZdhATMQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22I%20did%20not%20lift%20a%20finger%20to%20save%20his%20character%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

**lift a finger**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lift+a+finger)  an idiom

> To help with something. Often used in the negative to indicate a lack
>   of willingness to exert even the bare minimum of effort.

As in:

*I clean every weekend, and you never **lift a finger** to help!*

Answer (score 0):

To not take any action, to sit idly while knowing that something was happening to the character.